# What kind of resistive network are these?

Tags: identification, passive-networks, passive-components

Some years ago I purchased three big resistor bags at an Electronic Fair: since then I've been organizing their values in my drawers. I found also the something that seems a couple of resistive networks which nevertheless I am not able to identify ant thus I am asking for the community's help: this is their front
[image]

and this is their rear.
[image]

Their electrical schematics seems the  following

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZftYW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the "strange values", and moreover there are significant differences between the corresponding values of the second network (at the right in the front picture): precisely R1=88.3k, R2=5.0k, R3=97k, R4=100.5k, R5=5.1k, R6=91.5k (thought these values and the above ones can be considered "the same" under an appropriately low tolerance value).

**What I'd like to get**. I would like to get a data sheet or at least an indication of who may possibly have produced these devices, in order to figure out their precise characteristics.

Comment: I'm unsure what it is you wish to know.

Comment: @Andyaka, I'd like a data sheet or at least to know what kind of resistive network is. Perhaps I should state this clearly in the question body.

Comment: They might be ratiometric. Seems like a lot of effort to go to, and not improve upon off-the-shelf 1% resistors, say, but who knows. RER doesn't seem to be a manufacturer, at least one I recognize, or can find offhand. (Doesn't help that "RER" is also a series of MIL spec metal-case resistors.)

Comment: the ceramic is good for sharpening knives

Comment: @jsotola (LOL)  thank you... I've never though of such an application!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible to have custom resistor networks made, and quite possible that is what you have.

Ones such as these (odd values, unknown tolerance and stability, odd connection scheme) are unlikely to be very useful to anyone else, and probably they'd best find a new home in the e-waste recycling stream.

Comment: Thank you Spehro, I hope you are wrong but there's quite a possibility you're indeed right.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I neglected the possibility they might be useful in some artistic capacity.

Comment: (LOL)  Unfortunately I am not very skilled in those things,

Comment: From [Hackaday](https://i.imgur.com/IjTRHc0.jpg)

Comment: The one thing I'd add to this (realistic if regrettable) answer is that the lack of any serialisation etc. on the substrate suggests that they have /not/ been trimmed to precise values.

Comment: Thank you @MarkMorganLloyd; this would give a reason for the very different corresponding resistive values I found when measured them.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri There's something about the markings which is suggestive of Soviet-era electronics. Might possibly be East German. /If/ that is the case then there's a possibility that the circuit they were intended for has been very carefully designed to be tolerant of poor-tolerance components.